# Clicking through plots in Shiny app (V‘1.7.4)

Tags: r, shiny

I try to implement a popup window containing a plot from a single dataframe column. Similar to webpages I want to develop a previous and next button which generates the next plot of the next column. I followed an existing answers ([Clicking through plots in Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073501/clicking-through-plots-in-shiny-app)) which does not solve the problem any more.

I adapted the code to my needs in the server logic:

```
  # observer for qqplot interface
  observeEvent(input$qqplot, {
    showModal(qqModal())
  })

# the initial counter
  qq_count <- 1
  
# initial plot
  output$qqPlot <- renderPlot({
    df_0 <- df()
    sample_types <- unique(colnames(df_0))
    qqnorm(df_0[[sample_types[qq_count]]], main=paste("QQ-plot of ", df_0[qq_count]))
  })
  

# observer for the next button
  observeEvent(input$next_plot, {
    df_0 <- df()
    sample_types <- unique(colnames(df_0))
    
    qq_count <<- qq_count + 1

    if (qq_count <= length(sample_types)) {
      output$qqPlot <- renderPlot(
        qqnorm(df_0[[sample_types[qq_count]]], main=paste("QQ-plot of ", sample_types[qq_count]))
      )
    }
    else {
      qq_count <- 1
    }
  })    

# user interface as modal dialog
  qqModal <- function() {
    modalDialog(
      actionButton("previous_plot", "Show previous"),
      actionButton("next_plot", "Show next"),
      plotOutput("qqPlot"),
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Dismiss")
      )
    )
  }
```

I noticed that the observer is accessing the else condition, but is not changing the value of the `qq_count`.

The next problem I faced was including a `qqline` but this creates an additional plot. Generating the plot with ggplot is not working because the dataframe consists of duplicate columns.
Edit: when including `qqline` the app throws the error:

```
Warning: Error in int_abline: plot.new has not been called yet
  1: runApp
```

and crashes.

Do you have a solution for the problem?

Thanks and best regards
Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use a reactive value for the counter, and simplify as follows:

```r
# the initial counter
qq_count <- reactiveVal(1)

# plot the qq_count-th column
output$qqPlot <- renderPlot({
  df_0 <- df()
  sample_types <- unique(colnames(df_0))
  i <- qq_count()
  qqnorm(
    df_0[[sample_types[i]]], 
    main = paste0("QQ-plot of ", sample_types[i])
  )
})


# observer for the next button to increment the counter
observeEvent(input$next_plot, {
  df_0 <- df()
  sample_types <- unique(colnames(df_0))
  
  i <- qqcount()

  if(i < length(sample_types)) {
    j <- i + 1
  }
  else {
    j <- 1
  }
  
  qqcount(j)
})
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Including the ```qqline()``` within the ```renderPlot()``` creates the plots as I wanted. Thank you for your help.